# Почему я не могу использовать register/login с vite

Tags: typescript, vite

```typescript
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import axios from "axios"

interface RegisterFormData {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const RegisterForm: React.FC = () => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<RegisterFormData>();

    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<RegisterFormData> = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/register', data)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)

            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error));
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" {...register('email', { required: true })} />
                {errors.email && <span>Email is required</span>}
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" {...register('password', { required: true })} />
                {errors.password && <span>Password is required</span>}
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default RegisterForm;
```

В проекте без vite этот код работает, но с ним я постоянно получаю ошибку :
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404

Что делать чтобы исправить проблему я уже не знаю и проблема не в коде, а именно в попытке сделать регистрацию или залогиниться.